# Google sheets: inter-sheet formula seems to ignore MATCH criteria... (Copy data from one sheet to another using 1 Match criteria)

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, filter, match, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google spreadsheet with 5 tabs (sheets) and I want to copy rows of data from one sheet to another, IF a criteria matches in one of the sheet.

Sheet1 has hundreds of rows of data, across numerous columns. One of the columns lists dates. That column is mostly set to Date format. That date col also uses various Conditional Formatting rules. (I cannot change these or the formatting of this column!).

In sheet5 I have a formula that is supposed to look at sheet1 and find all the rows with a certain date in the date col and then copy the data in that row to a row in sheet5.

It looks like this: `=INDEX(sheet1!$A1:$O2002,MATCH($B$1,sheet1!$Q:$Q,0),0)`

It kind of works... if I just paste the formula in one cell in sheet5, it finds a row matching the date criteria and copies data over. But if I want to query more of sheet1, by dragging the cell down and find more rows of data to copy over... it just copies all the rows from sheet1 after the initial find... completely ignoring what it's comparing in `$B$1` to `$Q:$Q`... I suspect that what I think it's comparing in `MATCH($B$1,sheet1!$Q:$Q,0)` may not be what's actually happening, hence the result not matching my expectations...

Here is a screen capture of the sheet I want to copy data from: This sheet is set up and controlled by another party. I CANNOT change data; I CANNOT change data format that is already entered (eg I can't change a col set to Date to Plain Text!) See red notes.
But I can convert Dates in col N to Plain Text in col Q. Column Q is what I am querying/comparing in the formula in the destination sheet (see second screen capture below)

Sheet1 capture: data to copy, criteria date col[image]
In sheet5 I have this formula that queries sheet1:
`=INDEX(sheet1!$A1:$O2002,MATCH($B$1,sheet1!$Q:$Q,0),0)`

Here is a screenshot of what that formula produces in sheet5

Sheet5 capture: result of using formula[image]
Notice, it kind of works...(when I just paste the formula into my starting cell... it found the one line with the criteria I set) but then if I drag B3 down to query sheet1 more... it just grabs everything, even if $Q:$Q doesn't match the criteria set in B1...

Why?
Any help or clarifying questions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: To player0

Ok, here's a copy. You can view and comment. No edit.
Hope this helps.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C-NJjZ8f_KQHEpAnTGtcBsm8GVPxleAB0--XKM-NA5U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when dragging you did not lock the rows with `$`

your formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A1:$Q100, MATCH($B$1, Sheet1!$Q:$Q, 0), 0)
```

should be:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:Q$100, MATCH($B$1, Sheet1!Q:Q, 0))
```

coz with your initial formula you just created sort of a "sliding range" by every drag-down. to understand the formula... you are indexing range A1:A100  (from row 1 to row 100) where you narrow it down to just 13th row (MATCH outputs row 13 coz there is the match found. next you drag down and indexing range changes to A2:A101 but the MATCH formula always outputs 13 so 13th row from range A2:A101 is row 14, etc.

anyway, use this in Sheet5!B3 after you delete everything in B3:B range:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:P, Sheet1!N:N*1=B1*1)
```

Comment: Thanks player0, I'll give that a try. If it works, I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do what I want it to...  It finds one match but when I drag down it just repeats the same match.
See the google sheet link and result of formula used/dragged down from B3) [testFormula shared google sheet...comment only](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C-NJjZ8f_KQHEpAnTGtcBsm8GVPxleAB0--XKM-NA5U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @AZook like suggested, use FILTER (the last formula from answer)

Comment: So I replaced the formula (your fix) =INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:Q$100, MATCH($B$1, Sheet1!Q:Q, 0)) with the =FILTER... one and that seems to work. 
I must be dense, but I'm not sure then why I even need this at all... =INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:Q$100, MATCH($B$1, Sheet1!Q:Q, 0))
Either way, thanks for your replies. I'm learning something here.

Comment: @AZook iINDEX formula was just an explanation of what went wrong. you dont need it at all because FILTER formula will cover all your needs.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks!